# How to stop repeated request to enable bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Whenever I start/resume my android phone app, it will prompt me to enable my bluetooth twice, regardless what I choose on the first prompt message. What is wrong with my code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // BLE management
    private static BluetoothManager btManager;
    private static BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

    // Set the enable bluetooth code
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;


    // String for LogCat documentation
    private final static String DEBUG_TAG= "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();

        if (btAdapter != null) {
            if (!btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                // Request Bluetooth Adapter to be turned on
                Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }

        else
        {
       Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "No bluetooth available");
        }



        Button launchReminderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        launchReminderButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    // Launch Reminder
                                                    // Used Context's startActivity() method

             // Create an intent stating which Activity you would like to
             // start
             Intent reminder = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reminder.class);

             // Launch the Activity using the intent
             startActivity(reminder);
         }
                                                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // check for Bluetooth enabled on each resume
        if(btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        btAdapter = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int request_enable_bt, int result_enable_bt, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(request_enable_bt, result_enable_bt, data);

        if(result_enable_bt == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Turned On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (result_enable_bt == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Didn't Turn On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the following code,the key is `finish()` you used here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request_enable_bt,
        int result_enable_bt, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(request_enable_bt, result_enable_bt, data);

    if (result_enable_bt == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Turned On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else if (result_enable_bt == RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Didn't Turn On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

When you start your app,the system will remind you to turn on your Bluetooth,because your request Bluetooth on in `onCreate` method.When you `deny` the request, and the method `onActivityResult` call back,you will run the following code:

```
    else if (result_enable_bt == RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Didn't Turn On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

***The `finish()` will finish your Activity,every time when you click your app,when you click `deny` first time,and then you click `deny` second time.Every time you got this: `onCreate -> onResume`.So you get the request to enable your Bluetooth twice!***

Comment: That's all right!Please make my answer selected with the check mark,Thank you!

Comment: It's easy to solve this kind of problem,you can debug step by step.